# Adjusting Edge/Arrow Length in ggnet2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggnet2

I have made a network graph using ggnet2 and am wondering if there is any way to adjust the length of the lines that connect the nodes? I need the plot to be more compact.

The nodes are way too spaced out. If ggnet2 doesn't have an option, is there any way to program this with ggplot2?

sample code:

```
colour<- vector of group colour identifier
no_study<- vector of number of studies in the group
node.size<- vector of group standard deviation

plot <- ggnet2(network, color = colour, edge.size = no_study, node.size = standard_dev, label.size = 8)+ guides(color = "none", size = "none")
```

dput(df):
[image]

[image]

Thank you,
Samantha

Comment: Please share some code and reproducible data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Added some sample code. Thanks, Quinten

Comment: I am not sure how to use the dput(df) function because my data is not in this format.

Comment: Use `dput(df)` in your console and copy and paste the output to your question above.